# Can someone explain me

Tags: python

Friends please explain me:

Function name `getAnswer` with parameter `answerNumber`, but we have not assigned argument to function --- please explain how this program runs without error.

```
import random

def getAnswer(answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'It is certain'
    elif answerNumber == 2:
        return 'It is decidedly so'
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes'
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return 'Reply hazy try again'
    elif answerNumber == 5:
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 6:
        return 'Concentrate and ask again'
    elif answerNumber == 7:
        return 'My reply is no'
    elif answerNumber == 8:
        return 'Outlook not so good'
    elif answerNumber == 9:
        return 'Very doubtful'

r = random.randint(1, 9)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
print(fortune)
```

Comment: You _passed_ an argument when you called the function in `getAnswer(r)`

Comment: `r` is the argument to the function. What is not clear?

Comment: Your question denotes a lack of basic knowledge in OOP. Please make sure you follow some tutorials to understand better the semantics and the language itself

Answer (score 0):

You do assign an argument.

You use your `random.randint(1,9)` code to generate a random number.

This is your argument as you are passing this into your function and checking it against the various sets of criteria within it.

Comment: Thank you sir, I Understood. can you recommend some books for me to study well in python.

Comment: I'm not sure of books. I took a course on Udemy to teach myself. There is a lot of great material online. I would pick any course and follow it. At the start it will all be very similar